# Невозможно [пере]определять локальные функции

Tags: php

PHP 5.6 Каждый раз когда я пишу локальную функцию (функцию внутри другой функции) у меня выбивает ошибку "cannot redeclare". В чем проблема? Это же локальная функция. Какое тут к черту переопределение? Например:

```
class A {
    public function foo($x) {
        function bar($n) {
            return $n * 2;
        }

        return bar($x);
    }
}

$a = new A();
var_dump($a->foo(2), $a->foo(3));
```

Можно проверить [тут](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UUECxBEoha9Tr4FE).

Comment: вызывайте один метод var_dump($a->foo(2));

Comment: @Arsen, эмм с чего бы вдруг? Почему я не могу вызвать метод два раза? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте функцию записать в переменную

```
class A {
    public function foo($x) {
        $localFunction = function($n) {
            return $n * 2;
        };

        return $localFunction($x);
    }
}

$a = new A();
var_dump($a->foo(2), $a->foo(3));
```

Comment: Все-таки это очень нелогично... Переопределение - это когда одна и та же функция описана два раза в разных местах. Я бы сказал все-таки что это баг языка. Код функции то не меняется от вызова к вызову. Т.е. получается что локальные функции в языке как бы и есть, но использовать их невозможно в принципе.

Comment: Я бы предпочел уж тогда чтобы в принципе на локальные функции кидало ошибку сразу и IDE подсвечивало. Чтобы не вводить в заблуждение. (ну или изменить поведение чтобы работало как надо)

Comment: Ничего не противоречит. В питоне есть локальные функции и недавно даже в C# ввели. И ничего! Никому не мешает. Просто полезно инкапсулировать порой мелкую логику, используемую только в одной функции в отдельную функцию, которую например можно потом передать в какой-нибудь array_map, ну или просто несколько раз вызвать.

Comment: @DarkByte нашел решение вашей проблемы, поправил ответ

Comment: Да я в курсе и про первый и про второй варианты. Просто обидно что локальные функции не пашут, да еще и в заблуждение вводят... Ну ладно.

Comment: @DarkByte ну с этим стоит просто смириться) Сейчас еще в песочнице попробую на 7 php то же самое сделать, посмотрю что там)

Comment: Там тоже это не работает я проверял.

Comment: @DarkByte значит остается только вариант писать ее в переменную. честно - немного пришлось подумать над вашим вопросом, интересно было)

Comment: если записать функцию в переменную, то это будет анонимная функция. у автора вопрос об именованных глобальных функциях. это альтернативный вариант, но не отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: @teran я понимаю и вариант с проверкой, как вы приложили я предлагал в комментариях чуть выше, однако как по мне - запись через анонимную функцию лаконичней, вы не находите?

Comment: @СашаБоричевский лаконичней или нет, но анонимная функция будет доступна там, где есть на нее ссылка. обычная функция доступна в любом месте кода. ну и физическая реализация у них разная. Если цель - вызвать функцию единожды внутри данного метода класса, то конечно, анонимка выглядит куда удобнее.

Comment: Да анонимная функция вполне подходит. Просто неанонимная функция  смотрится немного органичнее (проще чтоли). Еще меня жутко бесит отсутствие стрелочных лямбд...

Answer (score 2):

ПХП вам говорит именно то, что происходит. Посмотрите на логику своего кода внимательнее. Ваш метод класса определяет новую функцию `bar`. Вот вызывали вы его один раз - определил. Теперь вызываете второй раз - и снова он пытается определить функцию `bar`, которая уже была определена в *глобальной области* при предыдущем вызове. Так что сообщение об ошибке вполне корректное функция  должна определяться только один раз. (для аналогии можете сравнить с определением констант)

Чтобы избежать такой ситуации, вам тем или иным способом надо проверить была ли уже определеная функция, самым простым тут будет использовать `function_exists()`

```
class A {
    public function foo($x) {

        if(!function_exists('bar')){
             function bar($n) {
                 return $n * 2;
             }
        }

        return bar($x);
    }
}
```

В таком случае метод будет определяться только при первом вызове.